# Hibernate 5: Inserting Data

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently, I am having this code to insert a `Product` object and it works totally fine!

```
public void insertProduct(Product product) {
    Session session = this.databaseDriver.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(product);
    transaction.commit();

    session.close();
}
```

However, this code does not seem to work:

```
public void insertProduct(Product product) {
    Session session = this.databaseDriver.openSession();

    session.save(product);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
```

What would be the reason for this? Neither does it give me any errors nor insert the data.

Comment: Your second codes's `save` is not inside a transaction.

Comment: @muja I am aware, but I also know that a Transaction is not necessary here.

Comment: Unless you use transaction-aware mechanisms like EJBs which use container managed declarative transactions by default, manually starting and committing / rolling back a transaction is necessary as you are doing in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hibernate even after calling session.flush it only updates an existing instance of the object not add a new one .Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

Comment: So how would I store it in the database?

Comment: stick with transaction.commit()